# MongoDB: The Date is displaying null instead of the date recorded

Tags: mongodb, date, collections, null

My query:

```
> db.Customer.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id": "$CustNum", "CustName":{"$first":"$CustName"}, "TransDate":{"$first":"$TransDate"}}}])
```

**The Result:**

```
{ "_id" : 103, "CustName" : "Jose Nicholas", "TransDate" : null }
{ "_id" : 102, "CustName" : "Maria Makiling", "TransDate" : null }
{ "_id" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz", "TransDate" : null }
```

**My Problem**: the date is returning a null value even though it has value on it.
I tried a couple of query like this:

```
> db.Customer.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id": "$CustNum", "CustName":{"$first":"$CustName"}, "TransDate":"$TransDate"}}])
```

The Error:

```
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'TransDate' must be an accumulator object",
    "code" : 40234,
    "codeName" : "Location40234"
```

I tried to do the `{$toDate: ... }`, and `{$dateFromString: ... }` still it doesn't work. The date in my MongoDB is  ISO format.

EDIT: This is what inside

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eba2cd2131bb04d04a820f"), "OR" : 1234, "TransactionDate" : ISODate("2021-06-09T16:00:00Z"), "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz", "ProdCode" : [ "b3", "b1", "s1" ], "ProdDesc" : [ "Milo 25grams", "Yakult 1 pack", "Piatos" ], "QTY" : [ 2, 2, 3 ], "Price" : [ 104.5, 45, 25 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eba2cd2131bb04d04a8210"), "OR" : 1235, "TransactionDate" : ISODate("2021-06-09T16:00:00Z"), "CustNum" : 103, "CustName" : "Jose Nicholas", "ProdCode" : [ "p1", "b2" ], "ProdDesc" : [ "Gardenia loafbread", "Tang Orange Juice 50" ], "QTY" : [ 2, 3 ], "Price" : [ 65, "30" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eba2cd2131bb04d04a8211"), "OR" : "1236", "TransactionDate" : ISODate("2021-06-17T16:00:00Z"), "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz", "ProdCode" : "p1", "ProdDesc" : "Gardenia loafbread", "QTY" : 1, "Price" : 65 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eba2cd2131bb04d04a8212"), "OR" : "1237", "TransactionDate" : ISODate("2021-06-17T16:00:00Z"), "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz", "ProdCode" : "b3", "ProdDesc" : "Tang Orange Juice 50", "QTY" : 1, "Price" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eba2cd2131bb04d04a8213"), "OR" : "1238", "TransactionDate" : ISODate("2021-06-17T16:00:00Z"), "CustNum" : 102, "CustName" : "Maria Makiling", "ProdCode" : [ "b3", "b1", "s1" ], "ProdDesc" : [ "Milo 25grams", "Yakult 1 pack", "Piatos" ], "QTY" : [ 2, 3, 1 ], "Price" : [ 104.5, 45, 25 ] }
```

**Also** is it possible to multiply an Array?

Comment: What are you grouping by? The sturcture is like this `db.collection.aggregate([{ $group: { _id:{field1:"$field1", field2:"$field2"}, totalData:{$sum:1}}}])`

Comment: show us the full document

Comment: You have given a wrong field name https://mongoplayground.net/p/eGSmhUs9nOR